# Is there any problem with the code or the problem exists in firebase datastore setup?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hw16M.png)Tried updating the security rules of firestore, still the problem is persisting.......it is getting authenticated and the storage is also working but it is not adding data to the collections in firestore.

```
const [err,setErr] = useState(false)
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const handleSubmit = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
        const displayName = e.target[0].value;
        const email = e.target[1].value;
        const password = e.target[2].value;
        const file = e.target[3].files[0];

        try{
            const res = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
            const storageRef = ref(storage, displayName);

            const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);

            uploadTask.on(
            (error) => {
                setErr(true)
            }, 
            () => {
                getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then(async(downloadURL) => {
                    await updateProfile(res.user,{ 
                        displayName,
                        photoURL: downloadURL,
                    });
                    await setDoc(doc(db,"users", res.user.uid), {
                        uid: res.user.uid,
                        displayName,
                        email,
                        photoURL: downloadURL,
                    });
                    await setDoc(doc(db,"userChats", res.user.uid),{})
                    navigate("/");
                });
            }
            );
        }
        catch(err){
            setErr(true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with security rules.  You are simply trying to access some object in Firebase Storage that doesn't exist. We can't tell you why that is because we can't see the contents of your storage bucket to know that it matches what your code is trying to do.